# Why my CSV file was start filling from the 2nd line?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I am exporting MySQL data successfully to a csv file. But in the csv file first line was empty and data starts from 2nd line. Below is my code.

```
$delimiter = ";";
$generated_date =  date("Y-m-d-H-i-s"); 
$filename = 'order_detail_report'.$generated_date.".csv";
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w+');    
fputcsv($output, array('Order Type','Order Number','EAN','Article #'),$delimiter);
```

sql query

```
<?php 
$lineData = array();
$query = "my select query";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqliConn,$query);
while($result= mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $lineData[] = $result;
    fputcsv($output, $lineData, $delimiter);
    unset($lineData);
}
```

Data was exporting successfully to csv but it was starting from 2nd line, any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

```
<?php
//header info for browser
$delimiter = ";";
$generated_date =  date("Y-m-d-H-i-s"); 
$filename = 'order_detail_report'.$generated_date.".csv";
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');    
fputcsv($output, array('Order Type','Order Number','EAN','Article #','Title','Amazon Price','ERP Price','Requested Quantity','Dispatch Quantity','Rejected Quantity','Cancelled Quantity','Delivery Date','Status','EDD','LDD','Dispatch Center','Order Received','Price Status','Country'),$delimiter);
?>
```

I just removed all my mysql related query and only using the above one.

Comment: _Small Point_ Why do `$lineData[] = $result;fputcsv($output, $lineData, $delimiter); unset($lineData);` when you could simply do `fputcsv($output, $result, $delimiter);`

Comment: _By data starts on second line_  Do you mean you get your column headings on line 2?

Comment: yes column heading starts from 2nd line

Comment: No reason why I am suggesting this, but as you are only writing to the output yo might humour me and try a `'w'` instead of a `'w+'` in the fopen parameter

Comment: sorry, I was trying from past 2 hrs  and  Changed from w+ to w, still same output.

Comment: It was only a totally unfounded guess, I was not expecting a yippeee. Are you sure that this is ALL the code that you are showing us?

Comment: Yes, even I tried by removing mysql related query  . I have edited code above. Please check

Comment: Hmmm, does this also happen if you write the csv to a real file

Comment: at the begining of the file I have this line of code  "require_once "../../../../../wp-load.php";  When I removed this line , Its starting from 1st line.

Comment: something in there must have been outputting a newline to the output stream

Comment: Ok, but can we remove first empty line from csv before outputting ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176350/discussion-between-user3408779-and-riggsfolly).